# Working with comma separated values in a pandas dataframe series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data in a pandas dataframe series which is a string of comma separated values e.g.

```
workid:1234, homeid:4567, schoolid: 6789
```

The string may contain empty or multiple values, and id numbers may be of variable length:

```
id_numbers
0
1   workid:1234
2   workid:2567, homeid:345, schoolid: 678
3   homeid:567, schoolid: 6789
```

I wish to create a new series 'workid' which only contains the `workid:xxxx` value.

```
work_id_numbers
0   
1   workid:1234
2   workid:2567
3
```

I have tried

```
df['id_list'] = df['id_numbers'].str.split(",")
```

which creates lists

```
id_list
0   
1   [workid:1234]
2   [workid:2567, homeid:345, schoolid: 678]
3   [homeid:567, schoolid: 6789]
```

I have tried to iterate through the lists to extract the `workid:xxx` value

```
for num in df['id_list']:
    if num.str.contains("workid", na=False) == True:
        df['work_id_number'] = num
```

However I have an error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'str'
```

It strikes me there would be may ways to approach this so I am open either to a correction of my method or an alternative method.

Comment: try : str(num).contains

Comment: That gives error: `AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'num'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with list comprehension:

```
df['id_list'] = [','.join(y for y in x.split(", ") if y.startswith('workid')) 
                            for x in df['id_numbers'].fillna('')]
print (df)
                               id_numbers      id_list
0                                     NaN             
1                             workid:1234  workid:1234
2  workid:2567, homeid:345, schoolid: 678  workid:2567
3              homeid:567, schoolid: 6789
```

Comment: This works also. I need to research list comprehension in order to understand what is happening.

Comment: @MrDave - Both solutions are nice, difference is my solution match multiple `workid` in one row. ;)

Comment: Both solutions work - thanks people - but I think I will choose this one as it has introduced me to list comprehension which I think may be particularly useful in pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['id_list'] = df['id_numbers'].str.extract("(workid[^\,]*)").fillna("")

# output

            id_numbers                         id_list
0   workid:1234                               workid:1234
1   workid:2567, homeid:345, schoolid: 678    workid:2567
2   homeid:567, schoolid: 6789
```

Comment: This works. I  will await other solutions before accepting as preferred solution.

Comment: @MrDave Sure. Happy to help. :)